# Javascript RegEx to c# RegEx

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have been trying to use the following RegEx for both c# and javascript . Its working fine for javascript but not for c# .

c# code

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string strMacRegEx = @"/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-f])[\da-f]{12}/i";
        string strName = "944a0c112129";
        bool test = Regex.IsMatch(strName,strMacRegEx);
        if(test)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Pass");
        }
        else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Fail");  // Returns Fail  
        }

    }
}
```

Javascript code

```
var test = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-f])[\da-f]{12}/i;
alert(test .test('944A0C112129'));//Returns true
```

Can anybody please help me how to make the above regEx work for c# too . Please help me to understand what this regular expression will do . I am very new to regular expression so cant really get why this particular regex is for

Comment: I don't think c# patterns need delimiters.

Comment: Can you please give a correct it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the outer `/` and the case-insensitive modifier `i`. You can use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` as third parameter to get a case-insensitive match.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strMacRegEx = @"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-f])[\da-f]{12}";
        string strName = "944a0c112129";
        bool test = Regex.IsMatch(strName, strMacRegEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pass");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fail");  // Returns Fail  
        }
    }
}
```

You can take a look into the [msdn quick reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a detailed regex explanation.

Your regex contains two "lookahead assertions". (I think you can remove them for your test case.) The interesting thing is `[\da-f]{12}`.
[\da-f] means: match any decimal digit or any character from a to f
{12} means: match the digital or character exactly 12 times.

Answer (score 2):

Create the pattern using class constructor. (I'm quite unfamiliar with C#)

```c#
string pattern = @"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-f])[\da-f]{12}";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
Regex myPattern = new Regex(pattern, options);
```

and later, check using `IsMatch` as follows:

```c#
myPattern.IsMatch( "944a0c112129" );
```

As for explanation of what the pattern is doing, you can use several of online pattern analysers, such as https://www.debuggex.com/ or https://regex101.com/ or http://regexper.com/ and so on.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong in doing bool test = Regex.IsMatch(strName,strMacRegEx,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); . I have tested with yours it works like a charm . But when i tried without using class constructor it breaks. Please help .